# How can I match strings with at least one word in common in R?

Tags: r, string, parsing, text

Dataframe 1 example:

```
NAME;                        CITY; STATE;  SURNAME;
Maria Antonia Sousa          A     X       Antonia Sousa
Josep Oliveira Carlos        A     X       Oliveira Carlos 
Jose Mario Augusto Farias    B     Y       Augusto Farias
Andre Gois Lucas             B     Y       Gois Lucas
```

I want to create a column `familyDummy` in the second dataframe that indicates people that share a least one word of their surnames with the surnames in the first dataframe, but only if they are from the same city and state. The same person may appear in both df's and I don't want to identify them as family. The df's don't have the same lenght.

Dataframe 2 example:

```
NAME;                    CITY;  STATE;    SURNAME;          familyDummy;
Maria Antonia Sousa      A      X         Antonia Sousa     0
Angela Oliveira Santos   A      X         Oliveira Santos   1
Fabio Silva Carlos       B      Y         Silva Carlos      0
Luan Gois Lucas          B      Y         Gois Lucas        1
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution to solve your problem. The solution first divides the `SURNAME` column, of both df1 and df2, into two surnames to check for individual matches (see df1_bis and df2_bis). Then, it cycles over all the entries of df2 to check if the exact `NAME` is **not** found in df1 and if at least one surname of each entry of df2 is found in df1. If these two conditions are met, it afterwards check if the `CITY` and `STATE` of these entries match in df1 and df2. If this is the case, then it assigns familyDummy as 1, if not, as 0.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Your data
df1 <-structure(list(NAME = c("Maria Antonia Sousa", "Josep Oliveira Carlos", 
"Jose Mario Augusto Farias", "Andre Gois Lucas"), CITY = c("A", 
"A", "B", "B"), STATE = c("X", "X", "Y", "Y"), SURNAME = c("Antonia Sousa", 
"Oliveira Carlos", "Augusto Farias", "Gois Lucas")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df2 <- structure(list(NAME = c("Maria Antonia Sousa", "Angela Oliveira Santos", 
"Fabio Silva Carlos", "Luan Gois Lucas"), CITY = c("A", "A", 
"B", "B"), STATE = c("X", "X", "Y", "Y"), SURNAME = c("Antonia Sousa", 
"Oliveira Santos", "Silva Carlos", "Gois Lucas"), familyDummy = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

# Divide surnames
df1_bis <- df1 %>%
  # Divide SURNAME into two surnames to check independently for each single surname
  mutate(surname1 = str_extract(SURNAME,"[A-z]+(?=\\s)"),
         surname2 = str_extract(SURNAME,"(?<=\\s)[A-z]+"))

df2_bis <- df2 %>%
  # Divide SURNAME into two surnames to check independently for each single surname
  mutate(surname1 = str_extract(SURNAME,"[A-z]+(?=\\s)"),
         surname2 = str_extract(SURNAME,"(?<=\\s)[A-z]+"))

df2 %>%
# Add the result as another column
  # Use map to cycle over each row in df2
  mutate(familyDummy = map(1:nrow(df2_bis), function(i){
    # Check if the same NAME is in df1 and df2, if it appears assign 0, if not, 1.
    dif_name = str_detect(df2_bis$NAME[i], df1_bis$NAME, negate = T)

    # Check if any of the surnames of df1 is in df2. If it appears, assign 1, if not 0,
    surname_same = ifelse(str_detect(df2_bis$surname1[i], df1_bis$surname1) | str_detect(df2_bis$surname1[i], df1_bis$surname2) | str_detect(df2_bis$surname2[i], df1_bis$surname1) | str_detect(df2_bis$surname2[i], df1_bis$surname2), 1, 0)

    # Get the indices in df1 of the cases that meet the two latter criteria
    temp <- which(dif_name == 1 & surname_same == 1)

    # Check if there are cases where at least one entry matches the two criteria
    if(length(temp) >= 1){
      # Check if city and state in df1 matches that in df2
      # I used %in% instead of == because there might be more than 1 match
      familyDummy = ifelse(df2_bis$CITY[i] %in% df1_bis$CITY[temp] & df2_bis$STATE[i] %in% df1_bis$STATE[temp], 1, 0)
      }else{ # If no case match the previous two criteria return 0
        familyDummy = 0
        }
    return(familyDummy)
    }))

#                    NAME CITY STATE         SURNAME familyDummy
#1    Maria Antonia Sousa    A     X   Antonia Sousa           0
#2 Angela Oliveira Santos    A     X Oliveira Santos           1
#3     Fabio Silva Carlos    B     Y    Silva Carlos           0
#4        Luan Gois Lucas    B     Y      Gois Lucas           1
```

Comment: I'm trying to run this code on two other df's and I am getting the error:

Erro: Problem with `mutate()` input `familyDummy`.
x Input `familyDummy` can't be recycled to size 2.
i Input `familyDummy` is `map(...)`.
i Input `familyDummy` must be size 2 or 1, not 10825.
i The error occurred in group 1: CITY = "X", STATE = "Y".

Can you help me with that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm, it should work without problems for the other two df's. Try checking if there are differences between the first two df's and the second ones (for example, differences in the column names).

Comment: V. Solózano, I was wondering if you could help me change this code for a different situation. I have five different dfs now, one for each year (2000, 2004, 2008, 2012 and 2016) and I decided to join them all together. So now I have an unbalanced panel. I want the variable "familyDummy" to identify relatives in previous years, for each person in each city. Now I also have a unique code that identifies each city.